# how to make the restart button works

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with my restart button. It should be start from beginning to random the questions and will continue till the end of the questions. I did reset count from one and reset the array back []. For example, I have 6 questions and I click restart when already on 3 question, it should back to one and continue to rest on them(like from one to 6) it is not 1 to 3.

```js
  var btnRestart=document.getElementById("restart");
  var btnNext=document.getElementById("next");
  var words = [{
    question: "HTML stands for",
    answer: "HyperText Markup Language"
  },
  {
    question: "What is a href?",
    answer: "Link location attribute"
  },
  {
    question: "What is extensions used to save HTML pages?",
    answer: ".html"
  },
  {
    question: "What type of video formats are supported by HTML5",
    answer: "MP4, WebM, Ogg"
  },
  {
    question: "What is _blank target attribute?",
    answer: "It is opens the document in a new window or tab"
  },
  {
    question: "How to handle events in HTML?",
    answer: "Using javaScript or jQuery."
  },
  {
    question: "What is _parent target attribute?",
    answer: "It is opens the document in a parent frame"
  }
];

randomQuestions();
var count = 1;

function randomQuestions() {
  count++;

  if (words.length > 0) {
    var tempWords = [];
    
      for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        tempWords.push(i);
      }
    

    //last question
    if (tempWords.length === 1) {
      btnNext.style.display = 'none';
    }

    let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * tempWords.length);
    const question = words.splice(index, 1)[0]
    document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = question.question;
  }

}

btnNext.addEventListener('click', function(){
    randomQuestions();        
});

btnRestart.addEventListener('click', function() {
  randomQuestions();
  tempWords = [];
  count = 1;
})
```

```html
<div id="question">
  <h4>Questions</h4>
</div>

<button id="next">Next</button>
<button id="restart">Restart</button>
```

Comment: Why do you need `if (tempWords.length === 0)`? You just assigned the variable on the previous line with an empty array, the condition has to be true. You can also make a copy of an array with just `var tempWords = [...words];`

Comment: Do you need to define ```btnRestart``` first? Like `const btnRestart = document.getElementById('restart')`

Comment: i did declare btnRestart on mycode...

Comment: You need to save the original value of `words` in a global variable. Then `btnRestart` can copy that into into `words` before it calls `randomQuestion()`.

Comment: don't declare `tempWords` locally inside the `randomQuestions` function. Declare it above scope heirarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have btnRestart, progress, and questTemp all defined.

If I understand correctly: your goal is for the questions to be initially scrambled. When `next` is pressed it moves on to the next question, and when `restart` is pressed it rescrambles all the questions and starts from the beginning?

## The main problem:

```js
...
const question = words.splice(index, 1)[0]
...
```

You are modifying the original array. You should keep the "words" list constant and only modify your copy:

```
...
const question = tempWords.splice(index, 1)[0];
...
```

### Other Improvements

This copy loop can be simplified with some code sugar:

```js
var tempWords = [];
for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    tempWords.push(i);
}
```

```js
var tempWords = [...words];
```

---

The variable `tempWords` here is completely out of scope. It doesn't exist outside of randomQuestions().

```js
btnRestart.addEventListener('click', function() {
  ...
  tempWords = []; //wrong
  ...
})
```

It seems that you might be using it in some other functions(?). You haven't posted the code, but I imagine you need to access it for selecting the next question.

To fix this, do not declare tempWords as a new variable inside `randomQuestions()`,
Change

```js
...
if (words.length > 0) {
    var tempWords = [] //change
...
```

To:

```js
...
if (words.length > 0) {
   tempWords = [] //change
...
```

Place it above the randomize function:

```js
btnRestart.addEventListener('click', function() {
  ...
  tempWords = []; //add
  randomQuestions();
  //remove
  ...
})
```

And declare it in the global scope:

```js
var count = 1;

var tempWords = []; //add

function randomQuestions() {
```

---

This if statement is completely unnecessary as it follows setting it completely empty (will always return true.)

```js
tempWords = [];
if (tempWords.length === 0) {//remove
   ...
}
```

---

After the changes suggested, this if statement will also be completely unnecessary as it should always return true:

```js
if (words.length > 0) { //remove
    ...
}
```

### All together:

```js
var words = [
    {
        question: "HTML stands for",
        answer: "HyperText Markup Language"
    },
    {
        question: "What is a href?",
        answer: "Link location attribute"
    },
    {
        question: "What is extensions used to save HTML pages?",
        answer: ".html"
    },
    {
        question: "What type of video formats are supported by HTML5",
        answer: "MP4, WebM, Ogg"
    },
    {
        question: "What is _blank target attribute?",
        answer: "It is opens the document in a new window or tab"
    },
    {
        question: "How to handle events in HTML?",
        answer: "Using javaScript or jQuery."
    },
    {
        question: "What is _parent target attribute?",
        answer: "It is opens the document in a parent frame"
    }
];

var tempWords = [];
randomQuestions();
var count = 1;


function randomQuestions() {
    count++;

    tempWords = [...words];

    // last question
    if (tempWords.length === 1) {
        btnNext.style.display = 'none';
    }

    let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * tempWords.length);
    const question = tempWords.splice(index, 1)[0];
    questTemp.innerHTML = question.question;
}

btnRestart.addEventListener('click', function() {
    randomQuestions();
    count = 1;
})
```

There are a few other things you could improve, but without the rest of the code it's hard to tell. But this should fix your issue and point you in the right direction.

Comment: I did try this code, but it doesn't works. The result similar with my code that I have